# List JmDNS Services in Android App

Tags: android, jmdns

I'm trying to list some JmDNS services that I discover in my Android app and whenever I call this method my app crashes in the emulator?  I tried commenting out blocks of code and code inside methods and it still crashes on the emulator.  Anybody have any ideas?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.jmdns.JmDNS;
import javax.jmdns.ServiceInfo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo.State;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * The main activity, which list the available services in the local network.
 * 
 */
public class ConnectActivity extends Activity {

private final static String LOG_TAG = ConnectActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// ===================View Models===================
// The view model of the service info list
private List<ServiceInfoViewModel> serviceInfoList = new ArrayList<ServiceInfoViewModel>();

private ServiceServer server = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connect);

    this.initViewModels();
    this.initEventHandlers();

    this.initMockData();

    if (!checkWifiStatus()) {
        // this.showToast("No wifi network!");
    }

    server = new ServiceServer("Whooznear");
    int startedPort = server.start();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Started at " + startedPort);


    ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    // This schedule a runnable task every second
    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        //Put Thread Code Here
        //refreshServices();
      }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


}

private void refreshServices() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "refresh services...");

            testUpdateService();

            JmDNS registry = null;
            try {
                registry = JmDNS.create();

                List<String> enabledServices = LocalEnvironment
                        .getEnabledServices(ConnectActivity.this);
                for (String serviceName : enabledServices) {
                    String serviceType = LocalEnvironment
                            .getServiceTypeByTitle(serviceName);
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Register service..." + serviceType);

                    String text = "Test service";
                    Map<String, byte[]> properties = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
                    properties.put("srvname", text.getBytes());
                    ServiceInfo service = ServiceInfo.create(serviceType,
                            "apache-someuniqueid", 80, 0, 0, true,
                            properties);

                    registry.registerService(service);
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "List service..." + service.getType());
                    final ServiceInfo[] services = registry.list(service
                            .getType());
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, services.length + " services ("
                            + serviceType + ") is found.");
                    ConnectActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            for (ServiceInfo service : services) {
                                serviceInfoList
                                        .add(new ServiceInfoViewModel(service));
                            }
                            notifyServiceListChanged();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void onRefreshButtonClicked(View source) {
    this.showToast("Clicked " + ((Button) source).getText());
    this.refreshServices();
}

/*private void onSettingsButtonClicked(View source) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    this.startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
}*/

private void onServiceListItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
        int arg2, long arg3) {
    ServiceInfoViewModel selectedService = serviceInfoList.get(arg2);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Selected service at " + selectedService.getServiceIp());
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("ServiceName", selectedService.getServiceName());
    intent.putExtra("ServiceAddress", selectedService.getServiceIp());
    intent.setClass(this, ProfileActivity.class);
    this.startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (resultCode) {
    case RESULT_OK:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

private void initViewModels() {
    ListView servicesListView = (ListView) this
            .findViewById(R.id.servicesListView);
    ListAdapter servicesListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
            serviceInfoList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            new String[] { "serviceName", "serviceDesc" }, new int[] {
                    android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
    servicesListView.setAdapter(servicesListAdapter);
}

/**
 * Initialize the event handlers
 */
private void initEventHandlers() {
    // Service List View
    ListView servicesListView = (ListView) this
            .findViewById(R.id.servicesListView);
    servicesListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    onServiceListItemSelected(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
                }
            });

    // Refresh Button
    /*Button refreshButton = (Button) this
            .findViewById(R.id.refreshServiceButton);
    refreshButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View source) {
            onRefreshButtonClicked(source);
        }
    });*/

    // Settings Button
    /*Button settingsButton = (Button) this
            .findViewById(R.id.appSettingsButton);
    settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View source) {
            onSettingsButtonClicked(source);
        }
    });*/
}

private void initMockData() {
}

private boolean checkWifiStatus() {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); // Network
        State wifiState = conMan.getNetworkInfo(
                ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();

        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IP Address:" + info.getIpAddress());
        LocalEnvironment.LocalIPAddress = info.getIpAddress();
        LocalEnvironment.LocalIdentity = info.getMacAddress();

        return wifiState == State.CONNECTED;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Check Wifi Status Failed!", ex);
        this.showToast(ex.toString());
        return false;
    }

}

private void notifyServiceListChanged() {
    ListView servicesListView = (ListView) this
            .findViewById(R.id.servicesListView);
    ((SimpleAdapter) servicesListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void testUpdateService() {
    String text = "Test hypothetical web server";
    Map<String, byte[]> properties = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
    properties.put("srvname", text.getBytes());
    ServiceInfo service = ServiceInfo.create("_html._tcp.local.",
            "apache-someuniqueid", 80, 0, 0, true, properties);
    JmDNS registry = null;
    Exception occuredEx = null;
    int serviceCount = 0;
    try {
        registry = JmDNS.create();
        registry.registerService(service);

        ServiceInfo[] services = registry.list(service.getType());

        serviceCount = services.length;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, serviceCount + " services found");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        this.showToast(ex.toString());
        occuredEx = ex;
    } finally {
        if (registry != null) {
            try {
                registry.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                this.showToast(ex.toString());
                occuredEx = ex;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void showToast(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void showToast(int id) {
    ListView servicesListView = (ListView) this
            .findViewById(R.id.servicesListView);

    Toast.makeText(this, servicesListView.getItemAtPosition(id).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

This is the code I'm using to call the method above:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, ConnectActivity.class);
ProfileActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532): Check Wifi Status Failed!
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10036 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1321)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:469)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:264)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity.checkWifiStatus(ConnectActivity.java:214)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity.onCreate(ConnectActivity.java:60)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 23:42:39.991: I/ServiceServer(1532): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
01-09 23:42:40.032: I/ConnectActivity(1532): Started at -1
01-09 23:42:40.041: W/dalvikvm(1532): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40    014760)
01-09 23:42:40.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1532): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
01-09 23:42:40.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1532): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 23:42:40.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer.serverThreadProc(ServiceServer.java:61)
01-09 23:42:40.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer.access$0(ServiceServer.java:57)
01-09 23:42:40.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer$1.run(ServiceServer.java:52)
01-09 23:42:40.693: D/dalvikvm(1532): GC_CONCURRENT freed 416K, 7% free 7200K/7687K, paused 6ms+27ms
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532): Check Wifi Status Failed!
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10036 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1321)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:469)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:264)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity.checkWifiStatus(ConnectActivity.java:214)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity.onCreate(ConnectActivity.java:60)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-09 23:42:41.041: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 23:42:41.151: I/ServiceServer(1532): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
01-09 23:44:09.541: I/ActivityThread(1575): Pub com.whooznear.android: com.whooznear.android.ProfileProvider
01-09 23:44:10.054: D/dalvikvm(1575): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 4% free 6337K/6595K, paused 247ms
01-09 23:44:10.112: I/dalvikvm-heap(1575): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.805MB for 588816-byte allocation
01-09 23:44:10.422: D/dalvikvm(1575): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 4% free 6903K/7175K, paused 265ms
01-09 23:44:10.791: D/dalvikvm(1575): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 6903K/7175K, paused 72ms+3ms
01-09 23:44:14.162: D/dalvikvm(1575): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 603K, 11% free 6667K/7431K, paused 68ms
01-09 23:44:14.334: D/dalvikvm(1575): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 7168K/7431K, paused 6ms+16ms
01-09 23:44:14.673: W/Profile(1575): Invalid profile, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 length=1
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575): Check Wifi Status Failed!
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10036 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1321)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:469)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:264)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity.checkWifiStatus(ConnectActivity.java:214)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity.onCreate(ConnectActivity.java:60)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-09 23:44:19.782: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1575):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-09 23:44:19.831: I/ServiceServer(1575): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
01-09 23:44:19.861: I/ConnectActivity(1575): Started at -1
01-09 23:44:19.872: W/dalvikvm(1575): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40    014760)
01-09 23:44:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
01-09 23:44:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-09 23:44:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer.serverThreadProc(ServiceServer.java:61)
01-09 23:44:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer.access$0(ServiceServer.java:57)
01-09 23:44:19.872: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer$1.run(ServiceServer.java:52)
01-09 23:44:20.242: D/dalvikvm(1575): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 7% free 7200K/7687K, paused 6ms+18ms
01-09 23:44:23.991: I/Process(1575): Sending signal. PID: 1575 SIG: 9
01-09 23:45:38.371: I/ActivityThread(1619): Pub com.whooznear.android: com.whooznear.android.ProfileProvider
01-09 23:45:38.651: D/dalvikvm(1619): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 41K, 4% free 6337K/6595K, paused 91ms
01-09 23:45:38.671: I/dalvikvm-heap(1619): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.805MB for 588816-byte allocation
01-09 23:45:38.9    01: D/dalvikvm(1619): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 4% free 6903K/7175K, paused 168ms
01-09 23:45:39.182: D/dalvikvm(1619): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 6903K/7175K, paused 6ms+27ms
01-09 23:45:42.671: D/dalvikvm(1619): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 603K, 11% free 6667K/7431K, paused 71ms
01-09 23:45:42.831: D/dalvikvm(1619): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 7168K/7431K, paused 6ms+4ms
01-09 23:45:43.192: W/Profile(1619): Invalid profile, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 length=1
01-09 23:45:49.541: W/Profile(1619): Invalid profile, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 length=1
01-09 23:45:49.821: D/dalvikvm(1619): GC_CONCURRENT freed 389K, 7% free 7214K/7687K, paused 6ms+6ms
01-09 23:45:55.831: W/Profile(1619): Invalid profile, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 length=1
01-09 23:45:57.022: D/dalvikvm(1619): GC_CONCURRENT freed 115K, 3% free 7549K/7751K, paused 8ms+21ms
01-09 23:50:58.672: W/Profile(1619): Invalid profile, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 length=1
01-09 23:57:17.532: W/Profile(1619): Invalid profile, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 length=1
01-09 23:57:18.632: D/dalvikvm(1619): GC_CONCURRENT freed 130K, 3% free 7857K/8071K, paused 10ms+7ms
01-10 00:08:48.752: I/ActivityThread(1662): Pub com.whooznear.android: com.whooznear.android.ProfileProvider
01-10 00:08:49.2    01: D/dalvikvm(1662): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 4% free 6336K/6595K, paused 198ms
01-10 00:08:49.241: I/dalvikvm-heap(1662): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.805MB for 588816-byte allocation
01-10 00:08:49.471: D/dalvikvm(1662): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 4% free 6903K/7175K, paused 196ms
01-10 00:08:49.712: D/dalvikvm(1662): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 6903K/7175K, paused 7ms+3ms
01-10 00:08:53.211: D/dalvikvm(1662): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 603K, 11% free 6666K/7431K, paused 69ms
01-10 00:08:53.391: D/dalvikvm(1662): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 7167K/7431K, paused 6ms+26ms
01-10 00:08:53.732: W/Profile(1662): Invalid profile, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 length=1
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662): Check Wifi Status Failed!
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10036 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1321)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:469)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:264)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity.checkWifiStatus(ConnectActivity.java:214)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity.onCreate(ConnectActivity.java:60)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-10 00:09:34.981: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1662):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 00:09:35.051: I/ServiceServer(1662): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
01-10 00:09:35.051: I/ConnectActivity(1662): Started at -1
01-10 00:09:35.081: W/dalvikvm(1662): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40    014760)
01-10 00:09:35.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1662): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
01-10 00:09:35.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1662): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 00:09:35.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1662):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer.serverThreadProc(ServiceServer.java:61)
01-10 00:09:35.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1662):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer.access$0(ServiceServer.java:57)
01-10 00:09:35.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1662):     at com.whooznear.android.ServiceServer$1.run(ServiceServer.java:52)
01-10 00:09:35.732: D/dalvikvm(1662): GC_CONCURRENT freed 416K, 7% free 72    01K/7687K, paused 7ms+278ms
01-10 00:09:52.712: I/ActivityThread(1699): Pub com.whooznear.android: com.whooznear.android.ProfileProvider
01-10 00:09:53.031: D/dalvikvm(1699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 4% free 6336K/6595K, paused 93ms
01-10 00:09:53.051: I/dalvikvm-heap(1699): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.805MB for 588816-byte allocation
01-10 00:09:53.171: D/dalvikvm(1699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 4% free 6903K/7175K, paused 79ms
01-10 00:09:53.431: D/dalvikvm(1699): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 6903K/7175K, paused 5ms+3ms
01-10 00:09:56.832: D/dalvikvm(1699): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 603K, 11% free 6666K/7431K, paused 82ms
01-10 00:09:57.031: D/dalvikvm(1699): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 7167K/7431K, paused 12ms+14ms
01-10 00:09:57.381: W/Profile(1699): Invalid profile, java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 length=1
```

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace in Logcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532): Check Wifi Status Failed!
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532): java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10036 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1321)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:469)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:264)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity.checkWifiStatus(ConnectActivity.java:214)
01-09 23:42:39.951: E/com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity(1532):  at com.whooznear.android.ConnectActivity.onCreate(ConnectActivity.java:60)
```

You need corresponding user-permission for checking wifi status (more specifically the ConnectivityManager API), add following permission into your app's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<!-- Note that to us JmDNS, you also need the following permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
```

Give it a try and see what happen, by reading your code, you probably got some other issues.

Comment: Can you please help in this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102899/jmdns-service-re-announce