# JMDNS Service re-announce

Tags: android, jmdns

I am registering a service over Wifi using JMDNS. I need to reannounce it periodically. I have checked

[ServiceInfo#setText(final byte [] text)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.jmdns/jmdns/3.4.1/javax/jmdns/ServiceInfo.java#ServiceInfo.setText%28byte%5B%5D%29)

[ServiceInfo#setText(final Map)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.jmdns/jmdns/3.4.1/javax/jmdns/ServiceInfo.java#ServiceInfo.setText%28java.util.Map%29)

and, both didn't worked for me. Is there any other workaround to do same?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find a fix for this? I'm running into the same issue right now. Thanks!